# UIButton not appearing on iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, uibutton, xcode7

I am making an app that has two buttons on the main screen. I have used auto layout and placed constraints that fit my needs for the app. On all iPhones but the 4s, both of the UIButtons show up, but on the 4s, one does while the other doesn't. Here are two photos of the simulator.

iPhone 5s: 
[image]

iPhone 4s:
[image]

As you can see, the "Log In" button on the 4s has no background. It is impossible to click on it. Any help in fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to check Z order of views in Xcode view debugger?

Comment: can you share your storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are saying that it is impossible to click it in 4S (and it is possible in 5S etc.) that means that the real button is missing from 4S.

If you have a label and a background white rectangle or second label as the real button, then you might miss some constraints for this rectangle/label. 
It appears that it is not centered horizontally related to the content view or related to the text label "Log in" (so it is lost in the far left or right of the view). Another possibility is that the width or hight becomes 0 due to missing constraint. If these options do not help, you may share your storyboard if you wish and especially the outline view, in order that you get more help from the community.